# What is the correct way to load polyfills and shims with Browserify

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

I'm building a web app and I'm getting to know and love Browserify. One thing has bugged me though.

I'm using some ES6 features that need to be shimmed/polyfilled in older browsers such as `es6-promise` and `object-assign` (packages on npm).

Currently I'm just loading them into each module that needs them:

```
var assign  = require('object-assign');
var Promise = require('es6-promise');
```

I know this is definitely not the way to go. It is hard to maintain and I would like to use the ES6 features transparently instead of having to "depend" on them via requires.

What's the definitive way to load shims like these? I've seen several examples around the internet but they're all different. I could:

- load them externally:

  ```
  var bundle = browserify(); 
  bundle.require('s6-promise');
  // or should I use it bundle.add to make sure the code is runned???
  ```

  The problem I have here is that I don't know which order the modules
  will be loaded in in the browser. So the polyfilling might not have happened
  yet at call sites that need the polyfilled functionality.

  This has the additional downside that backend code cannot benefit from these
  polyfills (unless I'm missing something).
- use `browserify-shim` or something similar. I don't really see how this would work for ES6 features.
- manually set up the polyfilling:

  ```
  Object.assign = require('object-assign');
  ```

Comment: IMHO, since your modifications are to spec, doing `Object.assign = Object.assign || require('object-assign');` and `window.Promise = window.Promise || require('es6-promise');` is a legitimate and relatively safe thing to do (someone would need to do browser sniffing and make bad assumptions for it to cause any trouble)

Comment: Yes, that's another issue but it is usually solved within the shimming libraries. They do `modules.export = Object.assign || require('object-assign');` so that the shim won't override the spec. My question is more focussed on how and where to load the shims with browserify.

Comment: Personally I'm doing basically a `bundle.add('shims.js')` with my shims in there.  So they run before any other code can be required.

Comment: ok, and how do you make sure the bindle gets run before anything else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't require polyfills in your modules, that's an anti-pattern. Your modules should assume that the runtime is patched (when needed), and that should be part of the contract. A good example of this is ReactJS, where they explicitly define the minimum requirement for the runtime so that the library can work: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html#browser-support-and-polyfills

You could use a polyfill service (e.g.: https://cdn.polyfill.io/) to include an optimized script tag at the top of your page to guarantee that the runtime is patched correctly with the pieces you need, while modern browsers will not get penalized.

Answer (score 2):

This is the method that I'm using. The key is that you have to **export your polyfill** properly at the top of your main entry file.

#### The following won't work:

```
// Using ES6 imports
import './polyfill';

// Using CommonJS style
require('./polyfill');

... // rest of your code goes here
```

#### You actually need to export the polyfill:

```
// Using ES6 export
export * from './polyfill';

// Using CommonJS style
var polyfill = require('./polyfill');

... // rest of your code goes here
```

Your polyfills will load correctly if you do either of the latter methods.

Below you can find examples of my polyfills.

#### polyfill.js:

```
import './polyfill/Array.from';
import './polyfill/Object.assign';
```

#### Object.assign:

```
if (typeof Object.assign !== 'function') {
  (function iife() {
    const ObjectHasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

    /**
     * Copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one source
     * object to a target object. It will return the target object.
     * @param  {Object}  target  The target object.
     * @param  {Object}  source  The source object.
     * @return  {Object}  The target object.
     */
    function shallowAssign(target, source) {
      if (target === source) return target;
      Object.keys(source).forEach((key) => {
        // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
        if (ObjectHasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
          target[key] = source[key];
        }
      });
      return target;
    }

    /**
     * Copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one source
     * object to a target object. It will return the target object.
     * @param  {Object}  target  The target object.
     * @param  {Object}  source  The source object.
     * @return  {Object}  The target object.
     */
    Object.assign = function assign(target, ...sources) {
      if (target === null || target === undefined) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
      }
      sources.forEach((source) => {
        if (source !== null) { // Skip over if undefined or null
          shallowAssign(Object(target), Object(source));
        }
      });
      return target;
    };
  }());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution that worked for me was to use  `bundle.add`

I split my bundle in 2 parts, `app.js` for app code, and `appLib.js` for libraries (this one will be cached as it does not change oftenly).

See https://github.com/sogko/gulp-recipes/tree/master/browserify-separating-app-and-vendor-bundles

For `appLibs.js` I use `bundle.add` for polyfills, as they must be loaded when the script is loaded, while I use `bundle.require` for other libs, that will be loaded only when required inside app.js.

```
polyfills.forEach(function(polyfill) {
   b.add(polyfill);
});
libs.forEach(function(lib) {
  b.require(lib);
});
```

The page loads these 2 bundles in order:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="appLibs.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" crossorigin></script>
    ...
</head>
```

This way it seems safe to assume that all polyfills will be loaded even before other libs are initialized. Not sure it's the best option but it worked for me.

My complete setup:

```
"use strict";

var browserify   = require('browserify');
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var gutil        = require('gulp-util');
var handleErrors = require('../util/handleErrors');
var source       = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var watchify     = require("watchify");
var livereload   = require('gulp-livereload');
var gulpif       = require("gulp-if");
var buffer       = require('vinyl-buffer');
var uglify       = require('gulp-uglify');


// polyfills should be automatically loaded, even if they are never required
var polyfills = [
    "intl"
];

var libs = [
    "ajax-interceptor",
    "autolinker",
    "bounded-cache",
    "fuse.js",
    "highlight.js",
    "imagesloaded",
    "iscroll",
    "jquery",
    "keymaster",
    "lodash",
    "medium-editor",
    "mime-db",
    "mime-types",
    "moment",
    "packery",
    "q",
    "rangy",
    "spin.js",
    "steady",
    "store",
    "string",
    "uuid",
    "react-dnd"
];


// permits to create a special bundle for vendor libs
// See https://github.com/sogko/gulp-recipes/tree/master/browserify-separating-app-and-vendor-bundles
gulp.task('browserify-libs', function () {
    var b = browserify({
        debug: true
    });

    polyfills.forEach(function(polyfill) {
        b.add(polyfill);
    });
    libs.forEach(function(lib) {
        b.require(lib);
    });

    return b.bundle()
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(source('appLibs.js'))
        // TODO use node_env instead of "global.buildNoWatch"
        .pipe(gulpif(global.buildNoWatch, buffer()))
        .pipe(gulpif(global.buildNoWatch, uglify()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});



// Inspired by http://truongtx.me/2014/08/06/using-watchify-with-gulp-for-fast-browserify-build/

gulp.task('browserify',['cleanAppJs','browserify-libs'],function browserifyShare(){
    var b = browserify({
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {},
        fullPaths: true,
        extensions: ['.jsx'],
        paths: ['./node_modules','./src/'],
        debug: true
    });
    b.transform('reactify');

    libs.forEach(function(lib) {
        b.external(lib);
    });

    // TODO use node_env instead of "global.buildNoWatch"
    if ( !global.buildNoWatch ) {
        b = watchify(b);
        b.on('update', function() {
            gutil.log("Watchify detected change -> Rebuilding bundle");
            return bundleShare(b);
        });
    }
    b.on('error', handleErrors);

    //b.add('app.js'); // It seems to produce weird behaviors when both using "add" and "require"

    // expose does not seem to work well... see https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/850
    b.require('app.js',{expose: 'app'});

    return bundleShare(b);
});



function bundleShare(b) {
    return b.bundle()
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
        // TODO use node_env instead of "global.buildNoWatch"
        .pipe(gulpif(!global.buildNoWatch, livereload()));
}
```

As you can see

Answer (score 1):

Or use the polyfill service at
https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/docs/